# VSTS goals and objectives

Tags: azure-devops

Associating VSTS backlog items to goals and objectives – I am new to VSTS. I am in the process of adding backlog items, features, etc, but I do not understand how to tie my personal and department goals to the backlog for tracking – any suggestions?

Comment: You need to read the VSTS overview first : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/alm-devops-features?view=vsts

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Requirements Management, then you can reference below articles:

- [Requirements Management in TFS: Part 1 (of 4): Overview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slange/2007/11/06/requirements-management-in-tfs-part-1-of-4-overview/)
- [How to manage requirements (specifications) on Visual Studio Team Services (TFS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793608/how-to-manage-requirements-specifications-on-visual-studio-team-services-tfs)

If you mean track the features and requirements you're developing, code defects or bugs, and other particulars using work items, then you can refer to below articles for details:

- Process Template - [Scrum process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/scrum-process?toc=/vsts/work/work-items/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts) for example, and [Scrum process
  work item types and workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/scrum-process-workflow?toc=/vsts/work/work-items/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts)
- [About work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/about-work-items?view=vsts&tabs=new-web-form), and the guide links in [Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/index?view=vsts)

And here is an instance of [Agile Work Item Management with Team Foundation Server](https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/tfs/agileworkitems/) for your reference.