# Storing requirements/specification documents in TFS on-premise

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, documentation, requirements

We're starting a new development project using on-premise TFS 2018, git and Visual Studio. In the past we've followed the Agile model of creating epics and user stories and putting the requirements/ui mockups and other details directly in the user stories.

After living through that approach, we don't want go back down that road for the following reasons:
1) Once that feature is shipped, it becomes extremely difficult to locate the info. Who remembers what feature was done in what user story?
2) No centralized place to store feature documentation. Of course, we all don't want take the waterfall approach of spending 2 years writing feature requirements, but there is something to be said of having a centralized place organized by feature area that contains the relevant documentation.
3) Have you ever tried to read an extensive user story with requirements acceptance testing through either the web interface or through Visual Studio? It gets old pretty fast having to read through a 8 line window.

What we would like to do is do a hybrid of documentation and reference a link to the doc in the user story.  The user story exists for sprint tracking, but the details are stored in the document.  After the feature/user story has shipped, we can refer to the doc.

Therefore the question becomes how to store this type of info in TFS and link to it so it can open with a link in the user story.  We know we can do this with SharePoint, but is it possible to do in on-premise TFS?

Comment: Any update on my below answer? If you found my answer is useful then please accept/upvote it so that it can help other community members

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not directly possible in TFS with outgoing with some 3rd party vendors like [Modernrequirements](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=edevtech-mr.inteGREAT4TFS) which will be **paid services**.

You could always use the CMMI template which is used for creating and managing requirement Workitems, but not for storing a huge set of requirements as you typically stored in requirement documents.

1. As you mentioned there are other ways like  Storing the documents in
   SharePoint, one drive etc., and link to the user stories
2. Creating a
   [markdown](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschleiden.markdown)
   in the user stories itself.
3. Check-in those documents in the version control(Git,TFVS)

Refer to this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968872/7073340) in order to understand it better.